# What options do I have for automating bindings with NInject

Tags: ninject

Rather than manually having to bind every class, what methods and patterns, if any, are recommended for automatically setting up bindings?

For example, the vast majority of bindings simply look like this:

```
Bind<ICustomerRepository>.To<CustomerRepository>();
```

Once modules get large, you can end up with 100s of bindings that all look exactly the same. Can this be automated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

check out the conventions extension:
https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions

```
        using (IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel())
        {
            var scanner = new AssemblyScanner();
            scanner.From(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            scanner.BindWith<DefaultBindingGenerator>();
            kernel.Scan(scanner);
            var instance = kernel.Get<IDefaultConvention>();

            instance.ShouldNotBeNull();
            instance.ShouldBeInstanceOf<DefaultConvention>();
        }
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what that is doing?

Comment: there are a couple of different BindingGenerators in this project that will scan your assemblies and create bindings in Ninject based on conventions.  the DefaultBindingGenerator used in this example looks for interfaces that have the same name as a concrete instance plus "I".  for example, in the above IDefaultConvention is bound to DefaultConvention.  there is also a RegexBindingGenerator if you want to specify rules for the bindings, and a GenericBindingGenerator for trying to automatically fulfill generic arguments to types.